# WCF X509 how to know the user and password on operation contract?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

NET Developers, how to know the user and password on operation contract with x509 authentication?

I have a validator class but I don't know how to extract the user and password during operation contract method.

I have a credential type "user name"

```html
<message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
```

Comment: The answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1365161/2911678)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please view the answer in this post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365161/2911678